# Como registrar formulario dinámico en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, formularios, codeigniter-3

Estoy realizando un sistema para el registro de los post de una pagina, la cuestión es que esta tiene una opción de agregar servicios. Ahora el sistema al dar click en agregar servicio lo realiza de forma correcta, la cuestión es al momento de realizar la inserción, ya que los check no los inserta en el servicio que corresponde, es decir al agregar 6 servicios y de esos solo se selecciona 2 de noche 1 semana y 3 mes, el problema que tengo es como realizar la inserción de forma correcta que cada check pertenezca a a cada uno de los servicios asociado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como esta el formulario:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputTituloServicio">Titulo Servicio</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tituloServ[]" id="inputTituloServicio" required>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="inputDescServ">Descripción del servicio</label>
                            <textarea name="descServ[]" id="inputDescServ" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="inputValorServicio">Valor del servicio</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="valorServ[]" id="inputValorServicio" required>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkNoche[]">
                                    Noche
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkSemana[]">
                                    Semana
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkMes[]">
                                    Mes
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Aparte de este se tiene otro grupo de campos que ya tiene solucionado, solo se tiene el problema en la parte del formulario dinámico, que al momento de recibir del lado del servidor no he podido asignar de forma correcta a cada servicio.
De esta forma lo recibo:

```
    $tituloPost     = $this->input->post("inputTitulo");
    $contenPost     = $this->input->post("contenido");
    $video          = $this->input->post("yout_vid");
    $file           = $this->input->post("file");

    $tituloServ     = $this->input->post("tituloServ");
    $descServ       = $this->input->post("descServ");
    $valorServ      = $this->input->post("valorServ");
    $checkNoche     = $this->input->post("checkNoche");
    $checkSemana    = $this->input->post("checkSemana");
    $checkMes       = $this->input->post("checkMes");
```

Como verán, al a ver una diferencia entre los array de noche, semana, mes no se pueden asignar de forma correcta a cada uno de los servicio, la cosa es que solo se puede agregar un valor por servicio.

Alguien puede ayudarme con este problema.

Comment: Si solo se puede agregar un valor por servicio ¿porque estas utilizando checkbox en lugar de utilizar radio button?.